# DISTINCT COUNT in SELECT CASE SQL

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement, case

I have a table of reports that include the fields `Case` (unique number), `ISR` (Individual Safety Report - unique number) and `YearsOld`.

There can be more than one ISR for each Case.  I want to count the number of unique Cases within age groups.

This SQL gives me a count of the number of ISRs:

```
SELECT  
COUNT(CASE WHEN `YearsOld` = -2) THEN 1 END) `No Report`,
COUNT(CASE WHEN `YearsOld` BETWEEN 0 AND 5) THEN 1 END) `0 to 5`
COUNT(CASE WHEN `YearsOld` BETWEEN 6 AND 12) THEN 1 END) `6 to 12`
FROM `Demographics`
```

is there a way to modify this to count the DISTINCT `Cases` for these Age Groups?

Comment: Always a possibility, but what if a case spans a person from 5-6 years old.  Do you want the count to be in the range that the case started, or the case where the person is associated with via most recent activity.

Comment: Can a `Case` have different `YearsOld` ages for different `ISR`?

Comment: Yes. An ISR is an Individual Safety Report on an adverse drug reaction.  There can be more than one ISR on a specific incident (submitted by two or more reporters), and there can be more than one ISR on the same Case for Adverse Events that happened to him/her on different dates.  Ideally, Case+DateOfEvent+YearsOld would be used to count the exact number of Adverse Events that happened to a Case at a given Age, but Date of Event is often omitted from the reports, so Case+YearsOld is as close as I can get to counting the unique Case+AdverseEvents.  Your solution below works great.

Answer (score 11):

If your "case" variable is unique, you can certainly put the distinct keyword in the SQL CASE syntax directly:

```
Count(distinct CASE when yearsold between 6 and 12 then case else null end)
```

That way, each unique value of the case variable is counted only once.

Just a note on column naming, I would suggest not using a word that has meaning in SQL if you have a choice (I.e. use 'case_num' instead of case).

Comment: Thanks, I agree on your note; `Case` is the fieldname in the existing table.

Answer (score 6):

You could use a subquery to filter your demographics table for a single `YearsOld` field per case, although if that case might have been related to difference ages for different `ISR` it'll only end up being counted in one bracket (perhaps this is what you want?):

```
SELECT
  ... -- as you currently have
FROM (
  SELECT `Case`, `YearsOld` from `Demographics` GROUP BY `Case`
) t;
```

Alternatively, to "count" each "distinct" "case" within each bracket, you do literally that:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `YearsOld` = -2 THEN 1 END) `No Report`,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `YearsOld` BETWEEN 0 AND  5 THEN `Case` END) `0 to 5`,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN `YearsOld` BETWEEN 6 AND 12 THEN `Case` END) `6 to 12`
FROM Demographics;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I want to count the DISTINCT `Case`+`YearsOld` which this does perfectly.